Is SSD wear-leveling affected by how much logical space you have left?
I've always been told that you should leave at least 20% of the SSD free because if you leave too little space in there, it's gonna wear off as it doesn't have a lot of space to work with. I do know that SSDs have a wear-leveling algorithm that erases whole blocks and writes them down in a different block to "spread out" the Flash Storage degradation, but does it still work out just as well if you've stored data in nearly all of the blocks? I'd imagine it would require a lot more moving around and thus more degradation overall to level out the wear in a ~95% full SSD compared to a 50% full one. So would the amount of blocks you've occupied contribute to faster degrading indirectly? How much of a SSD should you really save up to prevent this?

Is this a product usage or valid EE question?

The SSD Wear Leveling in Unallocated Space and Does wear leveling function normally without TRIM? answers on the https://superuser.com/ stack might help. This does seem a question more applicable to superuser.

@Justme, it's a fair "how does it work" or "how are these devices designed to work". It's a good question and it's about an electronic wear mechanism.

@Transistor Each vendor of SSDs use their own secret sauce. I have not heard that any modern SSD would benefit from leaving e.g. 20% of the disk unallocated. And most SSDs are already exposing less storage to users than what the chips actually have, e.g. 480 GB while having a 512 GB flash chips. I'd say, modern SSDs don't need any tricks, and if they do, then either implement the tricks and underprovision your paritition for slightly longer life or accept the shorter life. Or buy a better one that doesn't need any tricks. I think this is a SSD usage question, not EE.

@Justme, you've given a good SSD design answer in your comment.

From a comment on the question:

And most SSDs are already exposing less storage to users than what the chips actually have, e.g. 480 GB while having a 512 GB flash chips. - Justme

Choosing the right NAND on the Micron website shows Micron provide the following type of NAND devices:

Raw NAND : Raw NAND provides the lowest cost per bit but requires an external host controller (not contained within the package) to perform all management functions (e.g., ECC, FTL).
Managed NAND : Managed NAND provides simpler solutions and speeds time-to-market because the controller is embedded within the package to handle wear leveling, bad block management and ECC.

Looking at the some example parts:

Multilevel cell (MLC)  parts which are categorised as Raw NAND have capacities which are a power-of-two and range from 16Gb to 512Gb

Triple-level cell (TLC) parts which are categorised as Raw NAND have capacities which are a power-of-two and range from 256Gb to 8Tb

e.MMC memory parts which are are categorised as Managed NAND have capacities which are a power-of-two and range from 32Gb to 1Tb

Solid state drives which are categorised as Managed NAND have SSDs for automotive and industrial markets in which the SSD is available in a BGA package and includes a PCIe® /NVMe ™ interface:

The 2100 series parts have a capacity which is a power-of-two, but the 4150 series parts don't.


Based upon the comment from @Justme when I started to check the capacities of the Micron NAND parts I though that possibly:

The Raw NAND parts would have capacities which are a power-of-two and therefore expose all the internal storage. That is true based upon the above selection.
The Managed NAND parts may have capacities which are not a power-of-two, suggesting some of the internal storage is not exposed to support Over-provisioning, to avoid degrading performance due to having to perform wear-level management. This isn't true for all of the Micron Managed NAND parts checked. Also, for capacities quoted by Micron for the SSDs it doesn't seem to be specified what the "GB" is. For RAM and raw flash devices expect that to be be a 230 or 1,073,741,824 bytes. Whereas SSD or HDD manufacturers usually specify "GB" as one-billion or 1,000,000,000 bytes.

So, the above hasn't reached any definite conclusion to the question, which is probably SSD specific.
Perhaps searching data sheets or application notes for semiconductor manufacturers such as Micron which make managed NAND parts would find details on flash storage degradation.
I think this is an interesting question for embedded applications such as data logging that want to be able to log data to a SSD at a sustained rate, and not loose data if the underlying SSD degrades write performance due having to perform wear leveling. Most SSD datasheets just seem to specify write performance as "up to", with no definition of what the worst write performance might be.
